# Google Anlytics monitoring of events doesn't work properly

Tags: google-analytics

I've a problem with a function of Google Anlytics monitoring.
I want to track the download of a file on my web site and I wrote the following line:

```
<a href="/file_download/nomefile.zip" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', 'click', 'myFile']);">
```

But it seemes it doesn't work correctly. There are some downloads not shown and it seems to work only in a specific region: only tracks click from Italy, for example.
Can you give me any help or suggestion in order to resolve the problem, please?

Ps. I'm sure there are not tracking downloads because some people contacted me for support on the file and no event of download is shown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this implementation is that the page gets unloaded before the event is recorded. To solve you can do one of the following:

1. Use universal analytics. This implementation uses a function call which will get executed before unload.
2. Wrap the click in a function which will delay the unloading of the page by several hundred milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a novice in the use of Google Analytics. May you provide me with an example of Universal Anlytics, please? Or is there a Web Site where I can study it?

Comment: Universal analaytics is a new implementation of google analytics. You would have to set up a new profile to take advantage of it. More info here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en